# Magento Configuration ACL Mechanics

Tags: xml, magento, configuration, admin, acl

I want to let Magento manage my application's configuration items.

o How do you use Magento to store your configuration?
o Does the XML file that I add the items to make a difference?
o How do you put this information in the Admin screen?
o How do you change the placement of the new ACL permissions among the list of resource checkboxes (in the permissions/role screen)?

**I am opening this question with the intent of answering it later (there's a mandatory delay). Please don't vote it down.**

Dustin Oprea

Comment: So.. Don't answer this question because you're going to answer it instead?

Comment: That's not really what SO was intended for, perhaps you could do as others have and start a [blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication) or [wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations) on the subject.

Comment: One of the Stack Overflow founders explicitly hoped the site would be used for stuff like this.